# Subquery calculation error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, in-subquery

Why is this query not working?

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM 
                (SELECT *, (
                (((endingLatitude - " . $h . ")(endingLatitude - " . $h . "))
                /" . pow($r1, 2) . ")
                 + 
                 ((endingLongitude - " . $k . ")(endingLongitude - " . $k . "))
                 /" . pow($r2, 2) . "
                 ) AS point2 
                FROM (SELECT *, ((
                (
                ((startingLatitude - " . $h . ")(startingLatitude - " . $h . "))
                /" . pow($r1, 2) . ") 
                + 
                ((startingLongitude - " . $k . ")(startingLongitude - " . $k . "))
                /" . pow($r2, 2) . ")) 
                AS point1 
                FROM (SELECT * FROM trips WHERE distance >='" . ($distance * .25) . "') as query1)
                 as query2) as query3 WHERE point1 <= 1 AND point2 <= 1 LIMIT 0 , 10;");

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

$h and $k is the ellipses x and y coordinates respectively. I am using a formula found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76463) to calculate whether or not the two points, (startingLat,startingLong) and (endingLat,endingLong) are within an ellipse with vertical height $r1 and horizontal height $r2. I am also limiting the rows that I search to rows that have a distance cell value of greater than $distance * .25.

I think it might have something to do with a parenthesis error or something to do with the way I am sub querying/performing my calculations.

Using

```
die(mysqli_error($con));
```

returns an error of `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(endingLatitude - 36.9564753)) /796.842964388) + ((endingLongitud' at line 3`

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh it fails `if(!$result)` then prints, `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);`

Comment: put `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));` and check the real error you are getting. thanks.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh sorry about that, `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(endingLatitude - 36.9564753)) /796.842964388) + ((endingLongitud' at line 3`

Comment: add in your code please. don't put as comment. thanks

Comment: @anantkumarsingh done, any ideas of what the source of this error is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79082/discussion-between-anant-kumar-singh-and-henry-harris).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to use Mysql multiplication arithmetic operator, *.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_times

Instead of:

```
(endingLatitude - " . $h . ")(endingLatitude - " . $h . ")
```

Do this...

```
(endingLatitude - " . $h . ") * (endingLatitude - " . $h . ")
```

Comment: This could be it! Fixes the error, however, my query still does not function properly so it must be something else... I'll look into it.